# Mysql SLOW UNION query when using ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two tables: accessories and orders.

[accessories.category] contains a list of categories, i.e Red, Green, Blue ...
The orders table contains a list of past orders.

I want to select:

```
10 records from [accessories.category] WHERE category = 'Red' AND
10 records from [accessories.category] WHERE category = 'Green' AND
10 records from [accessories.category] WHERE category = 'Blue'
```

I also want to reference the orders table joining [accessories.catno] where it equals [orders.catno], show only products where [accessories.stocklevel] >0 and order the recordset by COUNT(orders.sold) DESC (show bestselling items first).

Because I wanted a set number of records from each category, I decided that a UNION ALL query would be suitable, and indeed it does work.
The problem is that it is not fast enough to put into production as it takes 0.3 seconds to execute on my development box.
If I remove the "ORDER BY sold DESC", the query takes just 0.0236 seconds, which is acceptable.  The problem is that I can't lose the ORDER BY.

BTW: I have indexed all the fields I need to.  Here is the query:

```
(SELECT 
accessories.catno, 
accessories.category, 
accessories.header, 
accessories.description, 
accessories.specialoffer, 
accessories.picture, 
accessories.unit, 
accessories.addinfo, 
accessories.post, 
accessories.price, 
accessories.vat, 
accessories.soundclip, 
COUNT(orders.catno) AS sold 
FROM 
accessories, orders 
WHERE 
orders.catno = accessories.catno 
AND 
accessories.category = 'Red' 
AND accessories.stocklevel > 0 AND 
accessories.category = 'Red' 
GROUP BY catno 
ORDER BY sold DESC 
LIMIT 10) 

UNION ALL 

(SELECT 
accessories.catno, 
accessories.category, 
accessories.header, 
accessories.description, 
accessories.specialoffer, 
accessories.picture, 
accessories.unit, 
accessories.addinfo, 
accessories.post, 
accessories.price, 
accessories.vat, 
accessories.soundclip, 
COUNT(orders.catno) AS sold 
FROM 
accessories, orders 
WHERE 
orders.catno = accessories.catno 
AND 
accessories.category = 'Green' 
AND accessories.stocklevel > 0 AND 
accessories.category = 'Green' 
GROUP BY catno 
ORDER BY sold DESC 
LIMIT 10) 

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
accessories.catno, 
accessories.category, 
accessories.header, 
accessories.description, 
accessories.specialoffer, 
accessories.picture, 
accessories.unit, 
accessories.addinfo, 
accessories.post, 
accessories.price, 
accessories.vat, 
accessories.soundclip, 
COUNT(orders.catno) AS sold 
FROM 
accessories, orders 
WHERE 
orders.catno = accessories.catno 
AND 
accessories.category = 'Blue' 
AND accessories.stocklevel > 0 AND 
accessories.category = 'Blue' 
GROUP BY catno 
ORDER BY sold DESC 
LIMIT 10)
```

Not sure if I am asking too much in this query or whether I need to re-think.
Any ideas?

Have added the output from EXPLAIN.

[image: Explain Output]

Comment: Are you sure you have an index on `sold`?

Comment: My guess is the problem is taking the `COUNT`. If you can denormalize it and update it with triggers it should run a lot faster.

Comment: show output from EXPLAIN on your query?

Comment: @MikeBrant: sold is a count, not a column, so no index

Comment: Well there is your problem, you are sorting on something that is not indexed.

Comment: @ysth:- Have added the output from EXPLAIN in original post.  Bit small, hopt it's readable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex suggests, you could make sold a column and keep it up to date with triggers.  Or you could run your query periodically (hourly? every 5 minutes? every 1 minute?) and save the results in another table (or better yet, cache the html I am guessing you are generating from it and avoid the query altogether).

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to not having an Index on sold because I changed `sold` to "COUNT(orders.price) AS sold" (orders.price IS an indexed field), and it made no difference to the query execution speed.

Comment: @Alex:- Thanks for your input :).  I created the field [orders.sold], populated it with a realstic random integer and set it as an Index.  I left in the ORDER BY sold clause, and the query execution speed shot up to 0.6 seconds.  Not sure I know why this is?

Comment: an explain on that query might tell you. you probably want a composite index on category,sold

Comment: This was NEVER going to work..  Even if I was able to optimise the query, the solution wouldn't be a scaleable one.

In the end, I created a new table of the top 20 best sellers of each category.  When I run this query, the execustion time is just:  0.0019 sec.  Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query although it is untested but give it a go

```
SET @level = 0;
SET @group = '';

SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
      accessories.catno,
      accessories.category,
      accessories.header,
      accessories.description,
      accessories.specialoffer,
      accessories.picture,
      accessories.unit,
      accessories.addinfo,
      accessories.post,
      accessories.price,
      accessories.vat,
      accessories.soundclip,
      COUNT(orders.catno)      AS sold,
          @level := IF(@group = accessories.category, @level+1, 1) AS level, 
          @group := accessories.category as E_Group 
    FROM accessories,
      orders
      left join orders
        on orders.catno = accessories.catno
    WHERE accessories.stocklevel > 0
    GROUP BY orders.catno, accessories.category
    ORDER BY orders.sold DESC
) rs
WHERE level < 11
```

Answer (score 0):

give a try to this query

```
 (  SELECT * FROM ( SELECT
accessories.catno, 
accessories.category, 
accessories.header, 
accessories.description, 
accessories.specialoffer, 
accessories.picture, 
accessories.unit, 
accessories.addinfo, 
accessories.post, 
accessories.price, 
accessories.vat, 
accessories.soundclip, 
COUNT(orders.catno) AS sold 
FROM 
accessories, orders 
WHERE 
orders.catno = accessories.catno 
AND 
accessories.category = 'Red' 
AND accessories.stocklevel > 0 AND 
accessories.category = 'Red' 
GROUP BY catno )
ORDER BY sold DESC 
LIMIT 10 )

UNION ALL 

( SELECT * FROM (SELECT
accessories.catno, 
accessories.category, 
accessories.header, 
accessories.description, 
accessories.specialoffer, 
accessories.picture, 
accessories.unit, 
accessories.addinfo, 
accessories.post, 
accessories.price, 
accessories.vat, 
accessories.soundclip, 
COUNT(orders.catno) AS sold 
FROM 
accessories, orders 
WHERE 
orders.catno = accessories.catno 
AND 
accessories.category = 'Green' 
AND accessories.stocklevel > 0 AND 
accessories.category = 'Green' 
GROUP BY catno )
ORDER BY sold DESC 
LIMIT 10)

UNION ALL

( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 
accessories.catno, 
accessories.category, 
accessories.header, 
accessories.description, 
accessories.specialoffer, 
accessories.picture, 
accessories.unit, 
accessories.addinfo, 
accessories.post, 
accessories.price, 
accessories.vat, 
accessories.soundclip, 
COUNT(orders.catno) AS sold 
FROM 
accessories, orders 
WHERE 
orders.catno = accessories.catno 
AND 
accessories.category = 'Blue' 
AND accessories.stocklevel > 0 AND 
accessories.category = 'Blue' 
GROUP BY catno )
ORDER BY sold DESC 
LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL (SELECT accessories.catno, accessories.category, accessories.header, a' at line 1

Comment: No luck i'm afraid.  Not sure about that nested SELECT?